# Angular $animate and directive not behaving properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ng-animate

So either, I'm just not getting it or the documentation is incomplete, or something else, but I can't seem to figure out my code, and what is happening.

I'm working on a directive that dynamically creates an overlay an generates a sliding menu. I've followed the solutions over several different questions and guides online. I've even read the angular documentation and nothing is working.

I can't get passed the initial creation of the background overlay. This is frustrating.

You start by clicking the icon button

`<i class='fa fa-bars' slider-menu></i>`

Then the slider-menu directive should activate and the css should take over.

**sliderMenu.js**

```
angular.module('dt').directive('sliderMenu', SliderMenuDirective);

SliderMenuDirective.$inject = ['$document', '$rootScope', '$animate'];

function SliderMenuDirective($document, $rootScope, $animate){
    return {
        link : function(scope, element, attr){
            var body = $document.find('body').eq(0);
            element.on('mousedown', function(event){
                $animate.addClass(body, 'menu-overlay');                    
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**css**

```
@keyframes menuOverlay{
    0% {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    100% {
        background-color: $navy-blue-alpha;
    }
}
.menu-overlay:after{
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    animation-name: menuOverlay;
}
```

Upon inspection on the initial click the only thing that is happening is the body tag gets the attribute of `data-ng-animate="1"`. Then nothing happens. I click again and then the body tag has a new class of `menu-overlay-add`. I have no idea what is going and am very lost. Can someone help point me in the right direction and maybe clarify animations just a little more, or show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: a plunker or fiddle would help identifying the problem better

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

`on` is a jQuery/jqLite method and does not automatically trigger the digest loop, which is why Angular's animation cycle isn't working correctly in your example.

You can use `$apply`:

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

For example:

```
element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    $animate.addClass(body, 'menu-overlay');
  });
});
```

Your animation also needs a duration specified:

```
animation-duration: 2s;
```

If you want the background-color from the last keyframe to remain you can use:

```
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Or the shorthand:

```
animation: menuOverlay 2s forwards;
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/6zTMlsNkg1xvKJpLs8dN?p=preview